# Apollo Server - how to create and add object in resolver when type isn't available in namespace

Tags: apollo, apollo-server

In the following example, I am attempting to create a post and add it to the Dictionary 'post'. How is the Mutation expected to create, add to the hash, and return the type of the item created when the item type isn't available to the namespace of the resolver?

```
mutation createPost {
  createPost(input: {name: "Post Name"}){
    name
  }
}
```

index.js:

```
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require('apollo-server');
const dictionary = {};
const typeDefs = gql`

    input PostSpecInput {
        name: String
    }

    type PostSpec {
        id: ID!
        name: String
    }

    type Mutation {
          createPost(input: PostSpecInput): PostSpec
    }

    type Query {
        post_specs: [PostSpec]
    }
`;

const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        post_specs: () => Object.keys(dictionary).map(function(key){
            return dictionary[key];
        })
    },
    Mutation: {
        createPost(parent, args, context, info) {
            var id = require('crypto').randomBytes(10).toString('hex');
                const postSpec = new PostSpec(id, args.input);
                posts_mock_database[id] =  args.input;
                return postSpec;
            }
      }
}

const server =  new ApolloServer({typeDefs, resolvers})

server.listen().then(({url}) => {
    console.log(`Server Ready at ${url}`);
})
```

Error:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "PostSpec is not defined",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "createPost"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
        "exception": {
          "stacktrace": [
            "ReferenceError: PostSpec is not defined",
            "    at createPost (index.js:38:34)",
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type definitions are not classes nor object instances, they are just for enforcing type. Even if you were in the namespace, calling 'new' would not work. Here is the solution for your mock database:

```
 Mutation: {
        createPost(parent, args, context, info) {
            var id = require('crypto').randomBytes(10).toString('hex');
                const newPostSpec = { id: id, name: args.input.name }
                posts_mock_database[id] = newPostSpec;
                return newPostSpec;
            }
      }
```

Comment: That really cleared up a fundamental misunderstanding of the underlying construction.